# Node.js - Reply to Instagram hub.challenge

Tags: api, node.js, callback, instagram

Pretty new to Node.js. I'm working on a project where I need access to Instagram's subscription/streaming API. Stuck on the handshake authorization, where my server needs to reply with a challenge code sent by Instagram.

The code to get and log the challenge code:

```
var http = require('http'),
url = require ('url');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var parts = parts.query['hub.challenge'];
    console.log(parts);
}).listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```

And the code to send the subscribe request to Instagram:

```
Instagram = require('instagram-node-lib');

Instagram.set('client_id', 'myClientID');
Instagram.set('client_secret', 'myClientSecret');
Instagram.set('callback_url', 'http://www.myLocalTunnelAddress/callback.js')

Instagram.media.subscribe({ lat: 48.858844300000001, lng: 2.2943506, radius: 1000 });
```

I can get the challenge code from Instagram's GET request, but have been working at this for a while and haven't been able to send it back. Does anyone have a suggestions as to how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this node.js library

https://github.com/mckelvey/instagram-node-lib/blob/master/lib/class.instagram.subscriptions.js

and how he implemented his handshake method:
https://github.com/mckelvey/instagram-node-lib/blob/master/lib/class.instagram.subscriptions.js

Comment: Thanks for this helpful library; it was helpful for me as well! Also, I just want to make sure if I understood the logic correctly or not? So in the callback that Instagram calls when there is any new media for the subscribed items(either by tag, by user,...) we need to handshake the 'hub.challenge' to the response and then call the appropriate `recent` method of `instagram-node-lib` for example: `Instagram.tags.recent({ name: 'myTag' });` or `Instagram.users.recent({ user_id: 123 });` and get the first object, right?